Is there a way to automatically remove the "Sum of" of all data fields in Powerbi?
I am creating charts with different inputs. When I add them to the chart, Powerbi adds the "Sum of" automatically to all of them. I want it to just say the input name, and the only way I have found to do it is to manually change them one by one through re-naming. Is there a more time saving efficient way to do it?
List of inputs
For example, I want it to just be "Seed" instead of "Sum of Seed".
I tried asking Chatgpt, did not produce good responses and I have googled to no avail. Only solution I have found was the manual way, but I cannot believe there is not a more efficient way to do it.

I don't think we can do that. Sum shows the column's Summarization function. You can manually change or create a measure.

You can change the "Summarize By" option of a column to None as shown below. I did it in Microsoft Fabric, but this same option should be available in Power BI desktop version as well. do it in the data model.

Here you can see the difference when I add the above and another column with default settings-

Note: You can also create measure on column with your desired Aggregation. That will also restrict applying the default Sum aggregation.
